# How to Select Multiple Column

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me to combine these Codes into one?

```
Range("B4:AU" & Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row).Select

Range("BI4:CU" & Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row).Select
```

to be like this

```
'**(this code wrong)**
Range("B4:AU, BI4:CU" & Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row).Select
```

I am trying to select multiple column in one code but only up to the bottom data of column "L"

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

Answer (score 3):

You need `UNION()`. Try-

```
Sub UnionSelect()
Dim lr As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row()

    Union(Range("B4:AU" & lr), Range("BI4:CU" & lr)).Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: but how i can SET it with Workbook and Sheets ?

Comment: Like this ```Set rngA = Union(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CI REG&TENYO&ADD").Range("B4:AU" & rl), Range("BI4:CU" & rl))```

Comment: @Sunny: close, but you need to qualify (specify the sheet) also for the second range. `Range("BI4:CU" & rl)` will access the active sheet. You will get a runtime error if your sheet "CI REG&TENYO&ADD" is not active (you can't union ranges from different sheets). As the code would look rather ugly, often either a `With`-clause or a worksheet variable is used.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 main ways you can combine two ranges. First is `Union` which Harun has demonstrated. The other way is what you are trying to achieve. If you record a macro and select the range manually then you will get something like this

```
Range("B4:AU100,BI4:CU100").Select
```

I am assuming that `100` is the last row. So the above code can also be written as

```
.Range("B4:AU" & 100 & ",BI4:CU" & 100).Select
```

or simply

```
.Range("B4:AU" & lRow & ",BI4:CU" & lRow).Select
```

Now putting this in a workable solution (**Untested**).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        .Range("B4:AU" & lRow & ",BI4:CU" & lRow).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Having said that, avoid the use of `.Select`. Work with relevant objects.

For example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Set rng = .Range("B4:AU" & lRow & ",BI4:CU" & lRow)
    End With
    
    '~~> Do what you want
    With rng
    
    End With
End Sub
```

And using `UNION`, you would do it like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    Dim RangeA As Range
    Dim RangeB As Range
    Dim CombinedRange As Range
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Set RangeA = .Range("B4:AU" & lRow)
        Set RangeB = .Range("BI4:CU" & lRow)
        
        Set CombinedRange = Union(RangeA, RangeB)
    End With
    
    '~~> Do what you want
    With CombinedRange
    
    End With
End Sub
```